# Dell XPS L720x (Windows 10) only permits two monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, intel-graphics, dell-xps

Here's my setup:

- Dell XPS L702x (Late 2011)
- Intel HD Graphics 3000 Graphics processor
- NVIDIA GeForce 555M Graphics processor
- One HDMI port, one MiniDP port
- Windows 10 Enterprise N x64

Under Windows 8.1, I could have a monitor plugged into both outputs without any issue at all. It gave me a total of three fully-functional screens.

With Windows 10, I am only permitted to have two monitors. The HDMI port is controlled by the NVIDIA graphics processor while the Intel processor controls the laptop screen and the MiniDP port. With two monitors of either configuration plugged in, the respective graphics processors work fine; however, if I plug a third in, the NVIDIA processor (HDMI) stops working.

By "stops working" I mean it literally ceases to function. If I open the NVIDIA control panel while outputting through it, it shows me all the functions of a typical NVIDIA video card; with the MiniDP port and HDMI plugged in, however, the HDMI screen goes black and the NVIDIA control panel turns blank. If I have both plugged in and then remove the MiniDP wire, the HDMI screen suddenly bursts into life again. It's as if the NVIDIA processor ceases to exist the moment the Intel processor is controlling more than one screen.

Windows 10's display configuration shows me 1/2 or 1/3 depending on what configuration I have plugged in, but never 1/2/3. It states "didn't detect another display" if I click 'detect'. This appears to be some sort of rogue power option or something.

Initially I blamed NVIDIA, but they're at least providing regular graphics updates - Intel can only be bothered to state that there's a "beta version of the HD Graphics 3000 driver on Windows Update" and gives out two links, one broken, to the website, which is pointless since it's all done through the control panel on post-XP systems.

Does anyone have any idea if there's anything I can do to fix this? I've become quite used to three screens; I see no reason to all of a sudden make do just because I've "upgraded" my OS. **Please don't just tell me to upgrade my machine. I'm looking for proper advice, not a different perspective.**

Device manager (even though only one processor works at once):
[image: Device Manager]

Comment: I would make a first guess that the Windows 10 installer placed a generic/barebones/basic display adapter for the Intel side. I had a similar problem installing Windows 10 on a Dell N5110, with the base adapter not using the full resolution of the display. I installed the Windows 8.1 Intel HD Graphics driver and the problem was resolved. You might give that a try.

Comment: BTW, I've got the *exact* same laptop and don't blame you one bit for not wanting to "upgrade." It's a *workhorse* laptop that is easily one of the best ones I've had and one of the smartest laptop designs (internally) Dell has put out there - especially with the cable-connected (rather than soldered-on) power jack. A recent drop of mine bent the jack, but I was able to replace it with a new one for $20 from a parts house. Great laptop...side rant off :)

Comment: It's a beast, isn't it? I wish you could still get the nine-cell oversized batteries. I'll give the installer a go - Intel gives a 404 when you try to download "win64_152822.zip", which is hilarious and depressing, but I found a mirror - and see what happens.

Comment: Installing the latest Intel driver does nothing alas.

Comment: You can't get the nine-cell batts anymore? Yikes - not even aftermarket? Mine is still typically good for about a 2-2.5 hour charge, but they're starting to overheat occasionally - and that's a sign they're on the downhill slide.

Comment: are you sure you installed the Windows *8.1* driver? That was what did the trick for me - going back to the last version.

Comment: Google "win64_152822.zip", that's what I downloaded - if you can find your driver, please tell me what it was.

Comment: Yeah, that's the right one, just double-checked it. Dang it. Man, that stinks. I've never had the three-monitor setup you've described, and I'd fight before I gave it up. Sure thought that 8.1 driver would fix it. Just for sanity's sake, post install does the Intel show as being driven by the Intel driver, not the MS "Basic Display Driver"?

Comment: I realize this is a huge straw-grasp, but have you tried tinkering with the button combos that enable-disable external displays as if you were connected to a projector? It *could* be a matter of Win10 doing things a little "differently" and explicitly *telling* it something that Win7 used to just...well...know/recognize. Like I said, huge longshot, but I hate for you to give up :)

Comment: I appreciate it all. By button combos, you're referring to Win+P? Or are there other combinations I ought to know about? Take a look at edited OP for a picture of what happens once Intel has wrested control from the NVIDIA processor.

Comment: My apologies for delays in getting back to this. I was referring to the alternate uses for the function keys indicated by the orange (on mine) glyphs, engaged by the Fn key. I was looking at Fn-F1 as a possibility for you...

Comment: Fn-F1 does the same thing as Win+P, I'm afraid; it doesn't enable or disable any screen functionality.

Comment: Rats. I'm afraid right now I'm out of answers, my friend. I can't fathom why they would change driver behavior like this; perhaps it's some subtle change at the OS level that has precipitated a change in the way the display drivers control the physical displays. If I find anything else that might be useful, I'll update here. If you find a solution, please update! :)

Comment: Dude, it looks like you're not the only one who has found Win10 to have broken a 3+ monitor setup. Look here: http://superuser.com/questions/947819/multiple-monitors-broken-with-windows-10-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and I do not believe this can be fixed.

I'm not going to pretend to understand the intricacies of WDDM but it seems to be something to do with version numbers and backwards compatibility. nVidia's GTX555M chipset has drivers that make it compatible with WDDM 2.0, which débuted with Windows 10; Intel have [outright stated](https://communities.intel.com/thread/61432?start=0&tstart=0) that the HD Graphics 3000 processor will *never* support WDDM 2.0.

This appears to result in Windows switching between the two WDDM modes; if a monitor is plugged into the Intel port, Windows switches to WDDM 1.2 compatibility mode, dropping support for nVidia's WDDM 2.0 support in the process.

Again, I'm not 100% about any of this but from a layman's point of view this appears to be the case. There are people going on in various threads about Intel HD Graphics drivers working for them, and they may, but it appears like laptops using the Intel HD Graphics 3000 chipset are not compatible with graphics processors capable of better performance on Windows 10.

Intel disappoint their customers once again

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to clone displays on my Dell xps15z by going to:
-device manager
-Right click on "Intel HD Graphics 3000" - disable

All function F1 modes work!
Please note: enable before restarting laptop!